# error in reading file line by line in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a text file which has the below content

```
bash-4.1# cat filelist.txt
js/config/organization.js
js/config/account.js
protected/config/settings.php
```

Below is the python script file. This script will read the files from above text file and upload the same files to Azure blob. I could read the file line by line using for loop. but is displays the line with `\n`. So, script is failing. Can someone please tell me how to read the exact line and replace wherever it is required?

```
bash-4.1# more blob_copy.py
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os

from azure.storage import BlobService
blob_service = BlobService()

for line in open('file2.txt','r').readlines():
    blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path('test', line, line)
```

When I tried to run the script, I got the below error.

```
bash-4.1# python blob_copy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blob_copy.py", line 12, in <module>
    blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path('test', line, line)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'js/wheelhouse/organization.js\n'
```

Comment: You don't really have all these `\n`s in your files, do you?  I'll remove them from your post.

Comment: Yes. you are right :) Thanks dude..\n is there only on the last line (in error message)

Comment: Whoops, removed one too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that as you read the lines, they still contain the terminating newline symbol (`\n`), which the file names don't.  The solution is to `strip()` the lines:

```
with open('file2.txt','r') as istr:
    for line in istr:
        line = line.strip()
        # Your code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import sys, os
list = open('file2.txt','r').read().splitlines()
for i in list:
    print i
```

It returns lines without newline character (\n).

Comment: @smartboy Then why have you accepted another answer lol? Anyways, I'm glad it helps...

Comment: @smartboy nope it's okay, since he was faster :) Problem is solved, that's what stackoverflow is for ;)

Comment: Yes :) stackoverflow is simply awesome!!